# Hypothesis testing and von Misher-Fisher distribution

Tags: distributions, circular-statistics

I have set of random unit vectors $x_i$, $i=10...30$. How to correctly test hypothesis that all of them from von Mises-Fisher distribution with unknown $\mu_d$ and $\kappa$ parameters, $d=128$?